# MYSQL Update value from same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have this table

```
id  child_id  root_id
====================
1     0        0
2     0        1
3     0        2
```

I want to update a row and change child_id to the id of a specific row with root_id as its id.

I have tried this mysql statement

```
UPDATE table SET child_id = id WHERE id = root_id;
```

An Example of the output i want is

```
id  child_id  root_id
====================
1     2        0
2     3        1
3     0        2
```

Comment: You should give an example of the results you want to get.  What you have described is that you want to set the `childid` to the `rootid`.

Comment: Your query references childid without an underscore and your example table references child_id with an underscore.

Comment: Ive fixed somethings in my question.

Comment: What is the Table name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update t1
set t1.child_id = t2.id 
from table t1
inner join table t2
on t1.id = t2.root_id
```

Please check, whether this is worked. Thanks

Comment: I get an error on from "from is not a valid input at this position"

Comment: I don't know the table name, you name change "table" to the real table name, see whether it worked

Answer (score 5):

You need to use update with join to itself.

```
update mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on t1.id = t2.root_id
set t1.child_id = t2.id
```